# Bug? "Reference to method is ambiguous" in Groovy

Tags: groovy

```
package bug
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class BugCheck
{
    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new BugCheck()
    }

    BugCheck()
    {
        new Child().method(1f)  // causes the problem
    }

    class Parent
    {
        void method(float f, boolean b=true)
        {
            println("Parent")
        }
    }

    class Child extends Parent
    {
        @Override
        void method(float f)
        {
            println("Child")
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling this piece of code with Groovy 2.3.4 leads to the following error:

*/mirror/dev/Groovy/src/bug/BugCheck.groovy: 17: [Static type checking] - Reference to method is ambiguous. Cannot choose between [void bug.BugCheck$Child#method(float), void bug.BugCheck$Child#method(float)]*

Is this a bug in Groovy, or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signatures vary, but since the `Parent` method has a default value, calling it with no `boolean` value creates an ambiguity: do you mean the `Child` method with no parameter, or the parent with a default `boolean`?

If `Child` declares a method with the exact same signature the ambiguity is resolved.

From a language design (or usage?) standpoint this is pretty shaky reasoning, though; IMO the `Child` method should be called if no `boolean` is provided. IMO the confusion is warranted.

Comment: Snell's like a bug to me. The default parameter will resolve to two methods, one of which is overridden in the child class. Might be worth putting in the groovy Jira